# How to see Database logs in Devel module

Tags: 7, database, debugging

I have installed [Devel module](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) in Drupal 7. I am able to see logs of error in each page I visit (when I am logged as admin), but, however, have not been able to see the database logs except in the Admin GUI, in the layer windows.

When I close the Admin GUI (without logging out) and visit other pages of my site, I cannot see the database logs. I installed Devel in other project long time ago, and I would dare to say that I saw these database logs in every page.

What is the recommended config: see all errors, and which template to use?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give Devel permissions to the user from which, you are logged in, and want to view logs.Go to People >> Permissions and give Devel permissions to the role you want to.

However, giving Devel permissions to anonymous user is a security risk. So, avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything, from giving permissions to all users (it is a web in development stage), re-installing Devel, re-building permissions, even hacking the database to erase any mention to Devel.

It turned out that the problem was in a single function, which called to a single View, which returned a number (a COUNT). This I discovered trying early gits.

I have replicated the View step-by-step and everything goes fine. The SQL is exactly the same. I am not interested on knowing what the error is, Drupal is not a trusty CMS and I cannot waste the precious time of my life trying to figure out the thousands of bugs that are left behind just to show some text, image and eventually sound in a browser, or, in other words, the thousands of bugs to cope with just to render a handful of HTML.